# historicalMCITP: Easiest Exam Based on Windows Server 2008

Tags: untagged

I know this seems like a silly question, but I wanted an exam under my belt fast for job-related politics, not technical ability.  I am not asking [for a repeat of a full testing path](https://serverfault.com/questions/91320/should-i-do-mcse-2003-or-mcitp-for-windows-server-2008). What is the easiest of the MCITP exams *focused on the Win 2k8 Server skills* that I can bang out quickly.  I am looking at the books, I just need to know which ones to buy.

Comment: Are you actually looking to get the MCITP certification or just MCP?

Comment: Well, there is a long-term interest short-term need, respectively answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Microsoft site to see what is covered by each exam.  The one which will be the easiest will be the one which covers the stuff you have been dealing with the most.

Comment: Agreed, the easiest way to pass an exam is to have done all the study without knowing it. Or having the answers... But that's not a good option.

Comment: @mrdenny I appreciate the sentiment, but I think we all know the exams cover little of what is day to day Windows sysadmin work.  I am technically desktop support in an enterprise setting.  I, along with my team, administer Win2k3 and Win2k8R2 boxes and we run a lot of license servers and other VMs. Group Policy is my bread and butter. I often spend working on customized Windows images (WAIK, MDT soon), and taming Windows with VBScript, batch files, and registry hacks.  So I assume [70-643](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-643&locale=en-us#tab2) is the one for me?

Comment: Following up on that comment, I really need to know what I can master on **the server exam track** with the least amount of time given my skill set.  I do not often plan out an AD domain, or implement a RODC; our entire environment is run by putzes who do not go beyond a Win2k functional level because that is what they know; the 640 is not going to be my strong point.  The Enterprise Desktop Admin stuff is informative and touches a lot on what I know, do, or read, but the emphasis is on server for a reason here.  Long story that has nothing to do with tech, all politics.

Comment: The technologies that are tested should be stuff that is used day to day.  The "Microsoft way" of completing the tasks may not really match the "real way" of doing things, but once you get used to the wording and you figure out how they expect things to be done passing the exams isn't that tough unless you take an exam which has a lab.  With the labs are nice because they don't require that you do it there way, just that you do it, but you have to actually know how to do it, reading from the books just won't do the trick.  Personally I've got like 15 MS certs, and I rarely study before hand.

Comment: @mrdenny I understand what you mean, but I think you fail to realize that there is reasons here beyond my control in which I need something that says SERVER in it. Haha.  If I had it my way, I would do the desktop stuff first. I came here for a quick answer about which test I should take, so I did not have to read all the website docs. But since this is going nowhere, I will pick up on that where I started on the site last night. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't be more help.